# How to safely kill postgres process?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, oracle-fdw

I have a plpgsql function. This function deletes and inserts some rows in some foreign table which is connected to OracleXE via oracle_fdw plugin. Every minute cron start 10 instances of this function for 10 different tables using psql. Sometimes (less than once per week) one instance stucks. It is in active state, but can't be canceled or terminated. 
I can kill it by SIGKILL but this will cancel all other postgres processes and start recovery mode.
Is it possible to stop this process without using SIGKILL?
(Postgres 9.3 on CentOS 7)

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend()` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE

Comment: >It is in active state, but can't be canceled or terminated. So pg_terminate_backend() or pg_cancel_backend() doesn't work.

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend()` can absolutely be used on a backed that is currently active (and `pg_cancel_backend()` as well - but that might take a while). What happens when you try `pg_terminate_backend()`?

Comment: pg_terminate_backend() returns true, but process still exists. The same happens when I sent SIGTERM via KILL command.